# How to make this table responsive?

Tags: html, responsive-design

Please help me how to make this type of table responsive, what I want I need each table below each other in responsive mobile and tablet layout.
In desktop view they are side by side.

Here's the link for demo:
 [Demo](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/110617870/Table/blockdiagram4.html)

Comment: Have you tried anything? Also, you might have to change the whole HTML structure...as `table` tags aren't the most responsive-friendly way to do it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) Have you tried learning responsive design, media queries etc or at least a google search..? if not, please do so. When you are stuck with a specific problem regarding that, bring it in front of the community…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create three divs all with a 33% width and left floated - give them the same class. You will need to clear the content below.

Using a CSS media-query for when your site reaches a certain width (i.e. a mobile device) you can change the div class styles to set the width of the divs to 100% and set float to none.

For your learning of media queries a great (live) example can be found [here](http://unmatchedstyle.com/sandbox/min-width/).